# Groovy: Dynamically create nested / combine maps in code

Tags: dictionary, groovy, nested, addition

I'm trying to dynamically create nested map like below in code.

```
def people = [
    [name: 'Ash', age: '21', gender: 'm'],
    [name: 'Jo', age: '22', gender: 'f'],
    [name: 'etc.', age: '42', gender: 'f']
]
```

So I can search it like below

```
person = people.findAll {item -> 
         item.gender == 'm' &&
         item.age == '21'}
```

My problem is that whilst I can dynamically create one dimensional maps in code, I don't know how to dynamically combine maps in code to create nested map e.g. let's assume in code I have created two maps **name1** and **name2**. How do I add them to **people** **map** so they are nested like above example?

```
def people = [:]
def name1 = [name:'ash', age:'21', gender:'m']
def name2 = [name:'Jo', age:'22', gender:'f']
```

I've searched / tried so many posts without success. Below is close, but does not work :(

```
people.put((),(name1))
people.put((),(name2))
```

Comment: Why not make `people` a List (`[]`) instead of a Map (`[:]`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `people` is a list of maps, not a nested map

So you can simply do:

```
def people = []
def name1 = [name:'ash', age:'21', gender:'m']
def name2 = [name:'Jo', age:'22', gender:'f']
```

Then:

```
people += name1
people += name2
```

Or define it in one line:

```
def people = [name1, name2]
```